# Intellij maven not exist

Tags: intellij-idea

`Maven` on the `intellij` was unavailable(think removed).I can not make new maven project or import dependency form `pom.xml` using: `right click->maven->reImport`.No maven option exist when right click.

Comment: Not clear what you are saying. You can simply go to File > New > Project for a new Project and for dependencies you have to be inside the pom.xml to be able to right click and see the Maven option.

Comment: excuse me !it was unavailable.I can not make new `intellij maven project `@dambros

Comment: It's option not exist

Comment: It's option not exist! I must say it's like that maven not be installed on the intellij!`restart intellij` I miss maven .@dambros

Comment: Go into settings and see if the maven config is correctly pointing to your maven install folder.

Comment: It's exactly my problem! when I open setting and search for maven no setting exist for maven.Like that all of maven was removed from IDEA !@dambros

Comment: Sounds like Intellij is corrupted. Delete the entire settings folder `.IntellijXX` from you users folder and see if it solves the issue.

Comment: thanks my friend.problem was solved by deleting `%USERPROFILE%\.IdeaICXX` .if you want add answer for another people...@dambros

Comment: Done, nice to hear it fixed the issue!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like the installation iscorrupted.

Remove the `.IntellijXX` or `.IdeaICXX` settings folder, which can be found under in the current user directory and after restarting Intellij, it should recreate everything fixing the problem.

Answer (score 6):

### Maybe Maven integration is disabled.

**Windows:** Navigate `File > Settings > Plugins`

**MacOS:** Navigate `Preferences > Plugins`

Then switch to `Installed` tab, search for `maven` and click `enable` button.

https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/managing-plugins.html

Answer (score 1):

Apart from getting the Maven option on right click on a project, there is a Maven option on the right hand side of intellij (As shown below, and highlighted). Click on the circle arrows icon for re-importing maven dependencies.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Usually if you open settings and search for the term "maven" you should be able to see under "Build, execution deployment" - "Maven" with its corresponding settings. The Maven Home directory should point to a valid maven installation. For example:
(unix

```
    $ /home/xy/intellij/plugins/maven/lib/maven3
```

If that doesnt work, try to reinstall intellij by either through intellij (windows software remove) or removing the config files in your home directory

(unix)

```
   $ /home/xy/.intellijXY
```

(windows)

```
   %USERPROFILE%\.IdeaICXX
```

Answer (score 0):

In the file menu select settings -> plugins.

search for maven, select maven, select enable. Restart intellij.

Once restarted you will now have the option to start new maven project and maven functionality will be accessible in all your previous projects.

Tried a few solutions but this is the only thing that worked. In short make sure maven is ON for you.

Answer (score 0):

Try navigating to the pom.xml file and open as a project.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Please phrase this as an explained conditional answer, in order to avoid the impression of proposing a debugging expermient instead of answering (for which a comment should be used instead of an answer, compare https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead ). For example like "If your problem is ... then the solution is to .... because .... ."

Comment: Worked for me but instead fo "open as a project", the option I chose was "open as a Maven Project".

Answer (score 0):

Maven is not integrated

Navigate to File > Settings > Plugins

Search for 'maven' here and add it

Click on enable and restart the intellij
You will be able to find 'maven'

Answer (score 0):

Like most of the people here, unfortunately, nothing has worked for me except,

There is a **"IDE and Project Settings"** button beside the search button, after clicking on it, there is an option of **"Enable new UI"** like below:
[image: IDE and Project Settings >> Enable new UI]

you need to click on it (and press Not Now); As soon as you click, all the Standard options like Project, Commit, Maven, Terminal, etc. will start restored permanently.

If any of the above options is not available try updating IntelliJ and then following the steps given in this answer.

I hope it helps resolve this annoying issue..

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

Right click on Pom.xml and click on add as maven project option (Windows)